# Font mixup with Neo Euler and Fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, libertine

For my document I would like to use Linux Libertine as main font and Neo Euler as maths font. However, there seems to be some conflict with the code I am using. Here is a MWE and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatextra, amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

% Main fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={LinLibertineCapitalsO}, SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}, , Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[LetterSpace=3, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}

\begin{document}

\emph{ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz}
\(ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz\)
\[ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz\]
\(1234567890\)
1234567890
\begin{align}
ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz
\end{align}
\[ \mathbf{\hat{x}} \iiint \mathbf{\dot{A}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: Euler or Linux Libertine?]

Note how there seems to be a mix-up between the two fonts. How can I make sure the correct fonts are selected?

Comment: I now realize that if I specify Neo Euler as my main font plainly by `\setmainfont{Neo Euler}` the commands `\textit` and `\textbf` do not have any effect. Thoughts?

Comment: because it has no bold or italic text fonts, text and math fonts are built and handled differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neo Euler is upright by design and currently math italic slots are empty (now I think this was a bad decision, but no time to fix it now), so `[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]` does not make much sense here and what you are seeing is the default Computer Modern math font, instead you should use `[math-style=upright]`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Euler really is a great typeface, but I am also convinced of the ISO standard for math typesetting. It is the most logical approach, so I will look into alternatives.

Comment: @tehingo, by design Euler is an upright italic (Hermann Zapf is to be blamed, I didn't design it `:)`), this is how things are and if you really want slanted italic, then Euler is not your best choice.

Comment: No blame to Mr Zapf, I'm sure he has his reasons `;-)`. Personally I prefer a different style, so I'll decide for something else `:-)`. Thanks again anyway!