# unicode-math: Double-struck math fonts

Tags: unicode-math, math-fonts

What is the math font of `unicode-math` that can get the following output:

[image]

since the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\symbb{R}$
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: duplicate of this, I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60014/traditional-german-sans-serif-and-serif-blackboard-bold-symbols/506634#506634

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The fonts there have results close to what I need but not identical. I would be happier if I could know how to get exactly the same style :)

Comment: The style you are looking for is provided by `amsfonts`, accessed by `\mathbb{R}`.

Comment: I guess the closest match could be from `mtpro2` but it is to be compiled with `pdflatex`. `\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lite,amsbb]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}\Huge
$\mathbb{R}$
\end{document}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am away to experiment, but can amsfonts be loaded along with unicode-math and compiled by lualatex?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to experiment, and haven't tried this before.  But this answer (using XeTeX) should provide useful guidance: [Unicode-math and `\Re`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70959/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mplus gets close:

[image: Mplus]

Note: Barbara is right.
[image: amsfonts]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
{\Huge $\mathbb{R}$}
\end{document}
```

So the answer would be: either a truetype/opentype version of amsfonts, or `unicode-math` can still use legacy fonts, if desired.

`unicode-math` access is by `$\symbb{R}$`.

=============

Original post:

I've seen that one before.

A sort of sans libertine/helvetica flavour.

Some random samples, none with a straight leg:

[image: a to l]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}


\newcommand\SampleText{\symbol{"211D}}


\newfontface\fra{Arial Unicode MS}
\newfontface\frb{Cambria Math}
\newfontface\frc{DejaVu Math}
\newfontface\frd{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}
\newfontface\fre{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontface\frf{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\newfontface\frg{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontface\frh{Fira Math}
\newfontface\fri{FreeSans}
\newfontface\frj{FreeSerif}
\newfontface\frk{FreeSerifAvvaShenouda}
\newfontface\frl{GFS Neohellenic Math}
\newfontface\frm{Honoka Antique-Kaku}
\newfontface\frn{Honoka Antique-Maru}
\newfontface\fro{HPMLinux Biolinum O}
\newfontface\frp{HPMLinux Libertine O}
\newfontface\frq{Kabala}
\newfontface\frr{Libertinus Math}
\newfontface\frs{Libertinus Mono}
\newfontface\frt{Libertinus Sans}
\newfontface\fru{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontface\frv{Libertinus Serif Display}
\newfontface\frw{Linux Biolinum}
\newfontface\frx{Linux Biolinum G}
\newfontface\fry{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontface\frz{Lucida Sans Unicode}

\newcommand\printther[2]{{#1\huge    \SampleText} -- #2}


\begin{document}


\printther{\fra}{Arial Unicode MS}

\printther{\frb}{Cambria Math}

\printther{\frc}{DejaVu Math}

\printther{\frd}{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}

\printther{\fre}{DejaVu Sans}

\printther{\frf}{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\printther{\frg}{DejaVu Serif}

\printther{\frh}{Fira Math}

\printther{\fri}{FreeSans}

\printther{\frj}{FreeSerif}

\printther{\frk}{FreeSerifAvvaShenouda}

\printther{\frl}{GFS Neohellenic Math}

\printther{\frm}{Honoka Antique-Kaku}

\printther{\frn}{Honoka Antique-Maru}

\printther{\fro}{HPMLinux Biolinum O}

\printther{\frp}{HPMLinux Libertine O}

\printther{\frq}{Kabala}

\printther{\frr}{Libertinus Math}

\printther{\frs}{Libertinus Mono}

%\printther{\frt}{Libertinus Sans}
%
%\printther{\fru}{Libertinus Serif}
%
%\printther{\frv}{Libertinus Serif Display}
%
%\printther{\frw}{Linux Biolinum}
%
%\printther{\frx}{Linux Biolinum G}
%
%\printther{\fry}{Linux Biolinum O}

\printther{\frz}{Lucida Sans Unicode}

{\fra \SampleText}
{\frb \SampleText}
{\frc \SampleText}
{\frd \SampleText}
{\fre \SampleText}
{\frf \SampleText}
{\frg \SampleText}
{\frh \SampleText}
{\fri \SampleText}
{\frj \SampleText}
{\frk \SampleText}
{\frl \SampleText}
{\frm \SampleText}
{\frn \SampleText}
{\fro \SampleText}
{\frp \SampleText}
{\frq \SampleText}
{\frr \SampleText}
{\frs \SampleText}
{\frt \SampleText}
{\fru \SampleText}
{\frv \SampleText}
{\frw \SampleText}
{\frx \SampleText}
{\fry \SampleText}
{\frz \SampleText}


\end{document}
```

====

For completeness, a fuller gallery, in parts, more systematically arranged.

(1) These are (some of) the ones with "Math" in the font name:

[image: mathr]

And then in order of decreasing coverage of the Letterlike Symbols unicode block:

(2)

[image: r2]

(3)

[image: r3]

(4)

[image: r4]

(5)

[image: r5]

(6)

[image: r6]

And arbitrarily stop there, with a coverage of 20 out of 80 glyphs in the block.

There is obviously something very interesting going on with fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.

Comment: You may add `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` to your gallery for future readers.

Answer (score 4):

Cambria Math uses a nearly-identical glyph. Ironically, you’d need to pay money for this copyrighted font, even though the reason you want it is that they ripped off someone else’s design.  (It’s owned by Microsoft and included with Windows and Office.  If you dual-boot Linux, you could make a symbolic link from the font file on your Windows partition to `~/.fonts` or `/usr/local/share/fonts`.  You could also buy the font from Monotype.)

You can select math alphabets or individual glyphs from the font of your choice with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range={bb,bbit}, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{CDHNRQSZ} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Pagella Math Sample]

Or with the font changed to:

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={bb,bbit}, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

[image: TeX Gyre DejaVu Math sample]

You can change only the ℝ with

```
\setmathfont[range=`ℝ]
```

or

```
\setmathfont[range=\BbbR]
```

Comment: How can I write a single instance of the uppercase `R` for once (on the go) in a font other than the main math font without having to write `\setmathfont[range=\BbbR]` in the preamble since I don't need a permanent change? For example, if I have `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={bb,bbit}, Scale=MatchUppercase]` in the preamble, how can I type `R` in `Cambria Math` for once inside some equation?

Comment: Declare it as a new math alphabet with `\setmathfontface`, e.g. `\setmathfontface\varbb{Some Font}`. Then use either `\varbb{R}` or `\varbb{\BbbR}`, depending on whether you want to use the font’s R or ℝ.

Comment: For the following, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfontface\varbb{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
$\symbb{R}~\varbb{\BbbR}~\symbb{\varbb{R}}$
\end{document}`, why is the third one different from the second? Is it because `\symbb` doesn't allow nesting?

Comment: Math alphabets don’t nest. It’s like how you write `\mathbfcal` instead of `\mathbf{\mathcal{...}}`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question please, how to edit your suggestion to accept only the letter `R` from my keyboard and get the output of its double-struck in, for example, `Cambria Math`?

Comment: To use the ℝ from a math font instead of the R from a decorative font, you can type in any of the following: `ℝ`, `\BbbR`, or `^^^^211d`.

Comment: `\setmathfont[range=\BbbR, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Cambria Math}`.

Comment: If you want the output of `\symbb{R}` to be different from ℝ, which I do not recommend, you can do this by setting `\varbb` as above, loading `newunicodechar`, and setting ℝ active with `\newunicodechar{ℝ}{\varbb{ℝ}}`.

Comment: `\setmathfont[range=\BbbR, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Cambria Math}` permanently sets `\BbbR` to be in `Cambria`, however, I don't look for commitment `:)`; I just need a way to change the font of `\BbbR` on the fly inside the equation for once.