# Does anyone know the name of this custom math font?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I was reading through a [textbook](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.952/2018SP/files/18.952_book.pdf) when, on page 13 (and a few other pages), I found an interesting font for the letter "L" which I have never seen before:

[image: L with a leading serif?]

Now, normally I would just use Detexify, but nothing came up when I tried this symbol. There is also a very similar letter "I" a few pages lower that looks like the L without the bottom line (but still with the leading serif on top). I then searched through a few lists of math fonts to see if I could find anything similar. My question is, does anyone recognize this font? I am slightly suspicious that this might not even be written in LaTeX, since the format of the textbook is very custom, and I find it weird that the author would choose to use some custom font when there are certainly suitable alternatives built in.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. you can follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507738/2288) approach to find what you need.

Comment: you have the pdf so you can list the exact fonts used in the document. This is a duplicate of this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: According to the pdf file's information, the document's text font is Minion Pro, and its (main) math font is Minion Math. Minion Math is a commercial font.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I didn't know I could do that

Comment: And thanks @Mico for doing it for me

Answer (score 2):

In this case, as Mico posted in the comments, you can use `pdffonts` or many PDF readers to list the fonts a PDF file uses.

Where that’s not an option, two good tables of font specimens are the [List of Symbols Defined by `unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) for OpenType math fonts, and [the `mathalpha` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) for legacy math fonts.

Comment: I not want to use the fontspec :-)...+1

Comment: pdffonts says it's Minion Pro (Math), but I've looked at the glyph list on their website and don't see a similar "L" (see @Sebastiano 's answer).

Comment: That’s indeed not on the glyph list for Minion Math 1.026, but it’s in the Minion Pro package.

Answer (score 1):

Here I add a MWE with of the free fonts. It is peraphs a discrete compromise with your Minion Pro (Math).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{enumerate}
     \item Introduce the following symmetrization operation on tensors $T\in \mathcal{L}_k(V)$:
\[\operatorname{Sym}(T)=\sum^{n}_{\tau\in S_k}{T^{\tau}} \]
\end{enumerate}
after text
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see the differences with a crop of the your pdf:

[image]