# unicode-math and amsfonts

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I'm testing unicode-math with LuaLaTeX but I miss the look of amsfonts blackboard bold letters like E, C R etc. Searching this site, I'm not the only one: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360607/unicode-math-but-ordinary-blackboard-bold), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507673/unicode-math-double-struck-math-fonts), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70955/unicode-math-and-re). Many of the questions are quite old, so I think a new question is not out of place. Two answers by SE luminaries to the most similar question are [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360609/18816) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360612/18816) but both define `\mathbb` as not unicode compatible. This means that, for example, `\mathbb E` looks right, but copying it from the PDF will result in a regular E.

Is there a way to make it look like amsfonts `\mathbb E` but still copy as the character ""?

Comment: Which font are you using fot `unicode-math`?

Comment: Find a unicode math font that has the look you want and replace the alphabet. That should work with copying, and if it does not, then you should file a bug report. (You could try newcomputermodern (book), maybe you like the blackboard bold alphabet in it.)

Comment: you can try different fonts, which have you tried? NewComputerModern might be closer but see ncm doc section 14.3 they may change

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Since the OP uses `unicode-math`, they should use `\symbb{E}` instead of `\mathbb{E}.

Comment: @Mico well yes in theory although by default it'll do the same thing and with the default latin modern math doesn't produce bb fonts in the style of amsfonts.

Comment: @Mico You mean for the symbol E? I'm still pondering the distinction between `math` and `symb` in `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Mankka `\symbb` is more correct (as it is a unicode shift, not a font change) but `unicode-math` makes `\mathbb` an alias for `\symbb` by default as it helps with moving things between pdftex and luatex (and users who never read the unicode-math doc so don't know about `\symbb`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdflatex/asmfonts

[image]

unicode-math/latin modern

[image]

unicode-math/Stix two

[image]

unicode-math/TeX Gyre Termes

[image]

unicode-math/New Computer Modern

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

$\symbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
  
\end{document}
```

I guess you are looking for TeX Gyre or NCM.

Comment: Thank you! I should have tried more fonts before asking. I guess `unicode-math` is made for mix-and-match like `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}` followed by `\setmathfont[range=\mathbb]{New Computer Modern Math}`?